# Efficient way to log/capture when a record is deleted

Tags: java, database, logging

Assume I have an employee table where the employee row can be deleted from any operation in the application.

I would like to capture the details efficiently whenever a row got deleted in the employee table.

- Adding a trigger (or)
- Enabling hibernate logging (or)
- Any other way..

I need to log the information like below

- The api which does the deletion or stack trace
- Which process delete the record
- Who and When the record got deleted

The above needs to go in production code base, so please help me with the efficient way...

Thanks.

Comment: You have not specified what "the details" are that you'd like to capture.  Are you only concerned about deletes from the application, or do you care if some other mechanism (e.g. DBA) executes direct SQL not via your application?  Where do you want the details to be written, in what format?  What is the measure for evaluating efficiency?

Comment: every time you delete a row,save action details in a new table for example.

Comment: 1. The api which does the deletion or stack trace 2. Which process delete the record 3. Who and When the record got deleted

Comment: 1. Inject an SQL in the respective SQL to insert into temporary table 2. Add a trigger to capture when it is deleted 3. Add a listener to the specific table if possible - in hibernate entity listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Inject an SQL in the respective SQL to insert into temporary table
2. Add a trigger to capture when it is deleted
3. Add a listener to the specific table if possible - in hibernate entity listener